# Draw an arc between two points

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm working on a proof of concept for an application that I think D3 might be a good fit for. Since I'm new to D3 I thought I would start off simple and build my way up to the application requirements. However, I seem to be hitting a snag on what I believe should be a very easy task with this library. I want to place two small circles on an SVG and then draw an arc or curve between them. Based on the documentation, I believe arcTo would be the best fit for this since I know the start and end points. For the life of me I cannot get it to draw the arc. The circles are drawn perfectly every time though.

```js
var joints = [{x : 100, y : 200, r : 5},
    {x : 150, y : 150, r : 5}];
              
var svg = d3.select("svg");

svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(joints)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });

svg.selectAll("path").append("path").arcTo(100,200,150,150,50)
  .attr("class", "link");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="800" />
```

I'm either going about this the wrong way or I don't fully understand how to append a path to an SVG. Can someone point me in the right direction? I haven't been able to find many examples of arcTo. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstood what `d3.path()` is. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-path):

> The d3-path module lets you take [a HTML Canvas] code and additionally render to SVG.

And for `d3.path()`:

> d3.path(): Constructs a new path serializer that implements `CanvasPathMethods`.

As you can see, the d3-path module has only a bunch of methods that allow you to take a HTML canvas code and use it to draw SVG elements.

That being said, you cannot use `arcTo` straight away in the SVG, as you are doing right now. It should be:

```
var path = d3.path();
    path.moveTo(100, 200);
    path.arcTo(100,200,150,150,50)
```

... and then:

```
svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", path.toString())
```

However, as an additional problem, `arcTo` is more complicated than that: the first two values are not the x and y of the starting point, but the coordinates of the first tangent.

Here is a demo, using different values for `arcTo`, which I think is what you want:

```js
var joints = [{
  x: 100,
  y: 200,
  r: 5
}, {
  x: 150,
  y: 150,
  r: 5
}];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(joints)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.r;
  });

var path = d3.path();
path.moveTo(100, 200);
path.arcTo(100, 150, 150, 150, 50);

svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", path.toString())
  .attr("stroke", "firebrick")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="250" />
```

An easy alternative is simply dropping the `d3.path()` and doing all this using just SVG code. There are plenty of examples showing how to draw an SVG arc from point A to point B with a given radius.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! I am finally seeing the arc drawn between the circles as desired. Marking this as the answer. Thank you for the quick and effective help!

Comment: Is there a way to make this databound similar to the way I did the circles?